# How to do an efficient loop with comparisons and insertions in other lists

Tags: python, django, list, loops

I'm working on a web application (Python/Django) which handle a big database and I need to optimize this loop in order to obtain a better execution time.

I have a list of entries, each entry has a yes_count attribute, a no_count attribute and a tid attribute.

I need to create two new lists depending of the ratio = yes_count / (yes_count + no_count)

Is it a better way to do it using built-in fonctions (or something even faster) ?

```
yes_entries = []
no_entries = []

for e in entries:
    if e.tid in tids:
        if e.yes_count > 0 or e.no_count > 0:
            ratio = e.yes_count / (e.yes_count + e.no_count)
            if ratio > 0.75:
                yes_entries.append(e.tid)
            elif ratio < 0.25:
                no_entries.append(e.tid)
```

Comment: What happens to entries that have yes/no_count <= 0? Are they meant to be ignored?

Comment: Why don't you do this in your database, it will be much faster than any python code.

Comment: Yes as @JochenRitzel said, all of this can be done *far more efficiently* in a single query in the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest making `tids` into a set for O(1) amortized lookup speed (as opposed to O(N) for lists):

```
set_tids = set(tids)
```

before the `for` loop, and then

```
if e.tid in set_tids
```

Otherwise the rest of the code you have given looks pretty optimized

Comment: Good advice, but we can't actually see if `tids` is already a `set` from the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can also save some time by only accessing `e.tid`, `e.yes_count` and `e.no_count` once, and store them in variables:

```
for e in entries:
    tid = e.tid
    if tid in tids:
        yes_count = e.yes_count
        no_count = e.no_count
        if yes_count > 0 or no_count > 0:
            ratio = yes_count / (yes_count + no_count)
            if ratio > 0.75:
                yes_entries.append(tid)
            elif ratio < 0.25:
                no_entries.append(tid)
```

You may also save time by caching no_entries.append and yes_entries.append:

```
yes_entries_append = yes_entries.append
no_entries_append = no_entries.append

for e in entries:
    tid = e.tid
    if tid in tids:
        yes_count = e.yes_count
        no_count = e.no_count
        if yes_count > 0 or no_count > 0:
            ratio = yes_count / (yes_count + no_count)
            if ratio > 0.75:
                yes_entries_append(tid)
            elif ratio < 0.25:
                no_entries_append(tid)
```

But at that point, you're maybe starting to get silly.

Another, probably even sillier, thing to try, is to see if using a filter is faster.  In python2, filter returns a list, meaning you're iterating over it twice, which is less than ideal.  However, we've got itertools to help us out there:

```
def filterfunc(e):
    return (e.tid in tids) and (yes_count > 0 or no_count > 0)

for e in itertools.ifilter(filterfunc, entries):
    tid = e.tid
    yes_count = e.yes_count
    no_count = e.no_count
    ratio = yes_count / (yes_count + no_count)
    if ratio > 0.75:
        yes_entries_append(tid)
    elif ratio < 0.25:
        no_entries_append(tid)
```

The next problem is that we're accessing the fields on e twice again.  Let's fix that with some iterator magic:

```
def filterfunc(t):
    tid, yes_count, no_count = t
    return (tid in tids) and (yes_count > 0 or no_count > 0)

for tid, yes_count, no_count in itertools.ifilter(filterfunc, itertools.imap(attrgetter(["tid", "yes_count", "no_count"]), entries)):
    ratio = yes_count / (yes_count + no_count)
    if ratio > 0.75:
        yes_entries_append(tid)
    elif ratio < 0.25:
        no_entries_append(tid)
```

It's up to you and your profiler to determine the best approach from all the options I've suggested.

Also, if you're using python3, use `filter` instead of `itertools.ifilter`, as it returns a generator rather than the list of python2's version.

Comment: Do these tricks really improve the performance? Just curious. I have very little knowledge about how smart (or dumb?) CPython is.

Comment: Yes, to a certain extent - but the actual amount gained is insignificant in all but the tightest loops.

Answer (score 0):

*Note:The following is an attempt at a more compact solution and may not necessarily be more efficient. Some profiling may be in order.*

I assume you're checking for `(e.yes_count > 0 or e.no_count > 0)` just so you won't end up with a division by zero. Assuming that's a very rare occurence, I would simply wrap the ratio calculation up as a function that handles `ZeroDivisonError` exceptions. In this case, we return zero for that edge case.

```
def get_ratio(y, n):
    try:
        return y / (y + n)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0
```

Next, we create a generator that iterates through the entries and returns the ratio and tid of candidate values.

```
tidset = set(tids)  # assuming tids is not yet a set()
ratios = ((get_ratio(e.yes_count, e.no_count), e.tid) 
            for e in entries if e.tid in tidset)
```

Finally, we  iterate through the generator and append them to the appropriate lists:

```
yes_entries, no_entries = [], []
for ratio, tid in ratios:
    (yes_entries, no_entries)[ratio < 0.75].append(tid)
```